# How to show error message from do_upload using codigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i create image module and i edit image more then 1mb then can not show errormsg.
i used codigniter fremwork.

**controller:**

```
   public function edit($id) {
        $this->edit_status_check($id);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agent_name', 'Agent Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile No.', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agent_vehicle', 'Agent Vehicle', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data = array(
                'page_title' => 'Edit Agent',
                'page_name' => 'agent/edit',
                'result' => $this->agent_model->select_id($id),
                'result_vehicle' => $this->vehicle_model->list_all(),
                'error' => validation_errors(),
                'id' => $id
            );
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        } else {
            $config['upload_path'] = '../uploads/agent/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg';
            $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
            $config['max_size'] = 1000; // 1 mb
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
      if (!empty($_FILES['agent_image']['name'])) {
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('agent_image')) {
                    $_POST['agent_img_url'] = 'uploads/agent/' . $this->upload->data('file_name');
                } else {
                    $data = array(
                        'page_title' => 'Edit Agent',
                        'page_name' => 'agent/edit',
                        'result' => $this->agent_model->select_id($id),
                        'result_vehicle' => $this->vehicle_model->list_all(),
                        'error' => $this->upload->display_errors(),
                        'id' => $id
                    );
                    $this->load->view('template', $data);
                }
            }
            $this->agent_model->update($_POST, $id);
            alert('Update', $_POST['agent_name']);
            redirect('agent');
        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
  public function update($data, $id) {
        $updatedata = array(
            'name' => $data['agent_name'],
            'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
            'password' => sha1($data['password']),
            'vehicle' => $data['agent_vehicle'],
            'address' => $data['agent_address'],
            'category' => $data['category'],
            'created_on' => date('Y-m-d h:i:sa')
        );
        if (!empty($data['agent_img_url'])) {
            $updatedata['img_url'] = $data['agent_img_url'];
        }
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('agent', $updatedata);
    }
```

**View:**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                            <img src="/<?= $result['img_url']; ?>" class="img-responsive" name="old_agent_image" width="133" height="100">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Agent Image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="agent_image">
                        </div>
```

MY question: I edit image for particular user then image uploaded,but if image size more then 1mb  ,then image can not upload and display error message.
so my question how to show errormsg.

Comment: `$data['errors'] = array("error" => $this->upload->display_errors());`

Answer (score 1):

```
$uploaded = $this->upload->do_upload('file'); //'file' is input field name

if($uploaded) {
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    // do database stuff
} else {
    $data['errors'] = array("error" => $this->upload->display_errors());
}
```

Comment: because i do not understand so you please write code

Comment: @kishankakadiya This is a [good example](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller) of how to use upload class in CI.